# How to propert check "manual standby" replication?

Tags: oracle

I was using the following query to check the last applied archivelog in my manual standby (basically a copy of archivelog from primary to standby and recover in destination)

```
COL NEXT_CHANGE# FOR 99999999999999
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
select thread#, 
    MAX(SEQUENCE#) AS MAX_SEQUENCE, 
    MAX(FIRST_TIME) AS "DATE",
    max(NEXT_CHANGE#) as NEXT_CHANGE#
from v$log_history
where RESETLOGS_CHANGE# = (select RESETLOGS_CHANGE# from v$database)
group by thread#;
```

But, recently, I had to restore the controlfile from primary database in this manual standby and this query did not work fine since it looks in `v$log_history`, which I assume that it read contents from controlfile. So the situation was: this query has reported the date of the last sequence (scn/timestamp) of primary database (because I just restored the controlfile from there), not the last sequence (or scn/timestamp) of the last change in the manual standby.

How to check manual standby properly?

Answer (score 0):

From [Oracle Data Guard, Concepts and Administration, 12c Release 1(12.1), E48552-08,
July 2017](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/manage_ps.htm#SBYDB00580),

> **10 Managing Physical and Snapshot Standby Databases**
>
> ***10.5.1.6 V$ARCHIVE_DEST***
> The following query shows the status of each redo transport destination, and for redo transport destinations that are standby databases, the SCN of the last primary database redo applied at that standby database:

```
SQL> SELECT DEST_ID, APPLIED_SCN FROM V$ARCHIVE_DEST WHERE TARGET='STANDBY';
   
DEST_ID    STATUS    APPLIED_SCN
---------- --------- -----------
2          VALID     439054
3          VALID     439054
```